# Animation with UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat does not repeat

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewanimation

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:speedOfCutout
                      delay:0.2f
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat //| UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^{

                     CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
                     animation.keyPath = @"position.y";
                     animation.fromValue = @77;
                     animation.toValue = @600;
                     animation.duration = speedOfCutout;

                     [cutout.layer addAnimation:animation forKey: @"basic"];
                     cutout.layer.position = CGPointMake(160, 61);
                     [cutout.layer addAnimation:animation forKey: @"basic"];
                     cutout.layer.position = CGPointMake(160, 61);

                     [cutout.layer addAnimation:animation forKey: @"basic"];
                     cutout.layer.position = CGPointMake(160, 61);

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL fin) {
                 }];

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(cutout.frame, shape.frame)) {
    cutout.hidden = YES;
    shape.hidden = YES;

    [cutoutMovementTimer invalidate];

    [self gameOver];

}
```

I have this code that is supposed to loop the animation until it runs into another shape. But, it only runs through once and does not do anything afterwords.

Comment: Could it be that it isn't working because your first option is not an option so it is ignoring all of them. I think  it should be `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut`

Answer (score 0):

You're using CoreAnimation object, will not affected by UIView Animation block, remove UIView Animation block and add:

```
animation.autoreverses = YES;
animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL;
```

It'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
set     `animation.repeatCount = -1;`
And is the completion block handle the shape change event and stop the animation.